# Error in imagecreatefromjpeg() function in PHP

Tags: php, image, jpeg

**When using the below php code it shows an error**

```
<?php
$path="/hari002244/album/f41b6b54811c.jpg";
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
?>
```

It shows

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(/hari002244/album/f41b6b54811c.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\newEmptyPHP.php on line 3
```

**But when using**

```
<?php
$path="f41b6b54811c.jpg";
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
?>
```

It doesn't show any error.

I had typed the path in URL bar and checked whether file exists.It is working perfectly.
Can you tell me why this error occurs? and also how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: url paths are RARELY directly applicable to file-system paths. They're two completely independent (but sometimes related) spaces.

Comment: @MarcB is right, the only common exception being the static resources under `public` or `public_html` or an equivalent directory (CSS, images, javascript, etc).  The files in this directory usually do map directly to a subset of the site's valid URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first path, `"/hari002244/album/f41b6b54811c.jpg"` is an absolute path, it starts from the root of the whole file system.  Chances are, this path does not exist.

In the second case, it is just a filename `"f41b6b54811c.jpg"` which is relative to / located in the current working directory, which of course exists.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer

Instead of `"/hari002244/album/f41b6b54811c.jpg"`

Should be used `"http://localhost/hari002244/album/f41b6b54811c.jpg"`